# Powershell locks up for any command

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Windows Server 2008 R2

When typing anything (or nothing) into PowerShell, and hitting enter it just locks up with a flashing cursor and does nothing for about 20 to 30 minutes. After waiting a long time, PowerShell works, it just takes a long time to initialize.

- I've installed Windows Management Framework 4.0 and rebooted
- I've tried SFC scan (no issues found)
- I've tried from a different user profile
- I've tried with the -noprofile switch
- I've tried with different PowerShell versions with the -version switch
- PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

Another thing I've noticed is that when starting version 1.0 or 2.0, I don't even get a command prompt, just a Windows PowerShell Copyright and a flashing cursor.

Everything else on the server works fine!

> PSVersionTable: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
>
> 4      0      -1     -1

Comment: Is this a domain member server or standalone playing server?  Is the server a VM and when you did your pristine build, did you create a snapshot? What role is the server playing? If this is real hardware, after you pristine build, did you do a full back up and capture the system state? If none of the above are true, you may be in a rebuild from scratch, or deal with the delay, as this sounds like a full environmental issue.

Comment: Domain member. It's actually the primary DC

Comment: Completely rebuilding from scratch seems pretty extreme without any troubleshooting. If it was such a serious issue you would notice other issues as well. Have you checked the event logs? Do you notice any other delays or issues with the server? Any hardware diagnostics done? I notice powershell always takes some time to initialize when I start it. I’ve found that I often have to press enter to kick start it and get a prompt. I imagine there is something it is doing and it just happens to be more problematic for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell very slow to open/respond](https://superuser.com/questions/578065/powershell-very-slow-to-open-respond)

Comment: I believe that caching was an issue.
I noticed that after leaving PowerShell to load, and waited, it seemed to speed up the subsequent time.

I applied that script as above, which should hopefully help. Will keep an eye on things. Thanks for the support so far