# Powershell doesn't run; displays empty window

Tags: powershell

After my system has been up for a while, I can't run powershell scripts.

- If I right-click a PowerShell script and run it: A console window is shown, "Windows PowerShell" in the title bar, but the window content is completely blank and the script doesn't run.
- If I run PowerShell from the Start Menu: A console window is shown, it displays the copyright notice and "Try the new cross-platform PowerShell", but I never get a prompt to type commands.
- If I run the cross-platform PowerShell from the start Menu: Copyright notice, a notice that I'm running version 7.1.1 and version 7.1.3 is available, but no prompt to type commands.
- If I run a normal command prompt, and run `powershell` from the command line: Same copyright notice, same "Try the new cross-platform PowerShell", but the powershell prompt never appears.
- If I run a normal command prompt, and run `pwsh` from the command line: Same copyright notice, 7.1.1 and 7.1.3, no powershell prompt.

This problem does get solved by a reboot, but I can't be rebooting 5 times a day just to run a basic script. So far, I have not been able to identify the trigger that makes PowerShell stop working.

Comment: You should obviously upgrade 7.1.1 to [7.1.3](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.3) to see if that is part of the problem. They fixed one very interesting bug with 7.1.3 that might be applicable. You might try removing your PowerShell [profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/578065/powershell-very-slow-to-open-respond)

Answer (score -1):

run as admin:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope LocalMachine
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

m.powers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).